# Jagged images on ViewSonic vx2239wm

Tags: images, lcd

I bought a ViewSonic vx2239wm LCD monitor. I connected my PS3 to it but I face a lot of jagged images. I have Batman Arkham Asylum on right now and I can actually feel the jagged images of the jail bars.

Is it such a bad LCD, did I make the wrong choice buying it? Or is it a bad HDMI cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jagged images are because the game engine is not [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) the rendered images. 's got nothing to do with the LCD.